# How do I unpin a package which is pinned by apt-listbugs

Tags: debian, apt

I have got binutils pinned by apt-listbugs -

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d$ cat apt-listbugs

Explanation: Pinned by apt-listbugs at 2018-03-25 06:42:33 +0530
Explanation:   #852035: binutils: bfd stumbles over duplicated symbols generated by gold
Explanation:   #852671: libkf5kipi: FTBFS (linking error)
Explanation:   #852672: libqapt: FTBFS (linking error)
Explanation:   #852899: libkf5kipi: FTBFS: libQt5Gui.so.5.7.1:(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of `__bss_start'
Explanation:   #852909: libqapt: FTBFS: libQt5Gui.so.5.7.1:(*IND*+0x0): multiple definition of `__bss_start'
Package: binutils
Pin: version *
Pin-Priority: -30000
```

Now I tried one of the ways which was listed which should have unpinned the priority or so I thought but it didn't -

```
 /etc/apt/listbugs$ cat ignore_bugs
    # List of packages or bug numbers to be ignored.
    852035
    852671
    852672
    852899
    852909
```

This is the full output of apt-cache policy -

```
 $ apt-cache policy
    Package files:
     100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
         release a=now
     500 https://riot.im/packages/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
         release o=riot.im,a=testing,n=stretch,c=main,b=amd64
         origin riot.im
     100 http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug experimental-debug/main amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=experimental-debug,n=rc-buggy-debug,l=Debian debug,c=main,b=amd64
         origin debug.mirrors.debian.org
     100 http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug unstable-debug/main amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=unstable-debug,n=sid-debug,l=Debian debug,c=main,b=amd64
         origin debug.mirrors.debian.org
     500 http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug buster-debug/main amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=testing-debug,n=buster-debug,l=Debian debug,c=main,b=amd64
         origin debug.mirrors.debian.org
     100 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental/contrib amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=experimental,n=experimental,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
     100 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental/main amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=experimental,n=experimental,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
     100 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/non-free amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
     100 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/contrib amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
     100 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
     500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=testing,n=buster,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
     500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=testing,n=buster,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
     500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
         release o=Debian,a=testing,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
         origin deb.debian.org
    Pinned packages:
         binutils -> 2.31-1 with priority -30000
         binutils -> 2.30.90.20180710-1 with priority -30000
```

The most interesting part lies in the last two lines.

The only pin-priority I have used is -

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: *
Pin: release a=buster
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release a=buster-debug
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 100

Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable-debug
Pin-Priority:100

Package: *
Pin: release a=experimental
Pin-Priority: 100

Package: *
Pin: release a=experimental-debug
Pin-Priority:100
```

so I try to have as much as a testing release as possible with the exception of browser and few other utilities which I need to be at forefront from my work.

Looking forward to how to unpin binutils. I know apt-listbugs has it own automated way of doing things. I don't want to disturb that.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to manually remove an `apt-listbugs` package pin is to delete it from `/etc/apt/preferences.d/apt-listbugs`. That is the only place `apt-listbugs` stores its pin information, so there’s no risk of inconsistency resulting from deleting pins there. Make sure you delete the `Package`, `Pin`, and `Pin-Priority` lines, along with all corresponding `Explanation` lines.

`apt-listbugs` takes `ignore_bugs` into account before it asks the user what to do about bugs present in packages to be installed (or upgraded). It doesn’t consider `ignore_bugs` when checking whether a bug in a pinned package still applies: a package is unpinned if all the bugs that caused it to be pinned are fixed, whether or not the bugs are listed in `ignore_bugs`, and adding a bug to `ignore_bugs` won’t make `apt-listbugs` consider it fixed.

Comment: I will try that. I was under the assumption that apt-listbugs automated it so it would do the pinning 'every time' per-se. Will try and see if that fixes the issue, thank you.

Comment: I checked the [manual](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt-listbugs/apt-listbugs.1.en.html), and `apt-listbugs` now states that "Each package pin is automatically removed by a daily cron job [...] as soon as the corresponding bug is fixed in [...] the package version available for installation or upgrade.", so the latter paragraph no longer applies today.